# How to rename single-digit numbers to sort incrementally?

Tags: rename, sorting, mv

What is the simplest way to add 0's to all single-digit filenames to make them sort correctly? I'd like to stick to the command line if possible.

From:

```
a_1.png
a_2.png
a_10.png
```

To:

```
a_01.png
a_02.png
a_10.png
```

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @gronostaj: Linux or OS X

Answer (score 0):

The script like following can do that

```
for i in *_?.*
do
   newname=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/\(.*\)_\([1-9]\..*\)/\1_0\2/')
   mv "$i" "$newname"
done
```

But note the script follows the naming convention in the question.
And note that it may overwrite existing files with the same names.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how to use the script?  Thanks.

Comment: usage:
run command line, 
change the current directory to directory with files you want rename and
write the script

Comment: How do you execute the script (or is this executed as you write it)?  Is any other software required?

Comment: Yes, you can write the script directly to the command line and it will be executed. It is not an optimal choice if you want to use it more than once. In this case store the script to a file and run it via _bash script-file-name_. No other software is required - just _bash_, _sed_ and _mv_. They are installe almost at all unix like systems.